# Putting the Skewness formula in R

Tags: r, statistics, skew

I need to put the attached skew formula in R and I have been having trouble calculating it. I cannot use base packages so the only way to do this is by creating the formula in R. Does anyone know if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

**Skew formula**

[image]

**My Code attempt**

[image]

Comment: Please post code as formatted text, not as a picture.

Comment: Glancing at your picture, it seems like you calculate things like the `mean` and the `sum` multiple times. If you're looking for efficiency, calculating those things once and storing the result in an object for re-use will be more efficient than calculating them twice.

Comment: I'm also surprised to see you using `min()`... I don't see anything in your formula that looks like a minimum.

Comment: `mean((x-mean(x))^3) / mean((x-mean(x))^2)^(3/2)`

Comment: Or `mean((x-mean(x))^3) / (var(x)^(3/2))`

Comment: @AllanCameron R uses the unbiased variance ie `n-1` instead of `n` which the formula has. if you use `var(x)` then you should multiply it by `(n-1)/n` in order to achieve the required results

Comment: `xRes <- x - mean(x); xSkew <- sqrt(length(x))*sum(xRes^3)/sum(xRes^2)^1.5`

Comment: @GregorThomas the formula uses Xi which I assume is the initial value of I, or the minimum

Comment: @AllanCameron why do you use the mean function. is the same as the formula I provided or just another version

Comment: @JohnDough the mathematical sum notation is showing that `i` should go from 1 to `n`. `X_i` refers to the `i`th value of `X`, the sum goes over all values of `X`.

Comment: @GregorThomas so it hypothetically it would be every value of x minus the mean added up

Comment: @JohnDough that's exactly it. Which, since R is vectorized, you can use `sum(x - mean(x))`, as you can see in some of the other comments.